# Ignore properties when mapping derived type instance

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's the simple hierarchy:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to clone `Derived` instances, but I want to skip `Id` values. So, I'm configuring mapper this way:

```
        Mapper
            .CreateMap<Base, Base>()
            .Include<Derived, Derived>()
            .ForMember(_ => _.Id, expression => expression.Ignore());

        var original = new Derived
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "John"
        };

        var clone = Mapper.Map<Derived>(original);

        Console.WriteLine(clone.Id == 0); // writes 'False'
```

Regardless of `ForMember` call, the value of `Id` is mapped.

This configuration:

```
        Mapper
            .CreateMap<Derived, Derived>()
            .ForMember(_ => _.Id, expression => expression.Ignore());
```

works as expected, but this is not an option, because it needs to set `ForMember` for each derived type.

Automapper version is 2.2.1.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to `Ignore` also the `Id` property on the base class mapping?

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Base, Base>()
    .ForMember(_ => _.Id, expression => expression.Ignore())
    .Include<Derived, Derived>()
    .ForMember(_ => _.Id, expression => expression.Ignore());
```

> [...]convention has a higher priority that Ignored properties in the
>   base class mappings[...]

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance

Comment: `Include<Derived, Derived>` returns `IMappingExpression<Base, Base>`. So, `ForMember(_ => _.Id, expression => expression.Ignore())` is called for `IMappingExpression<Base, Base>`. Hence, I'm ignoring `Id` property exactly on the base class mapping. Calling `Ignore` twice (for `Base` and `Derived`) is a nonsense, because this is the same as create separate mappings for every type in hierarchy.

Comment: Nevertheless, you're right. I've read mapping sources priority more attentively. I think, the last two (inherited `Ignore` and convention-based) must be swapped, but nobody cares. Didn't expect such stupid thing from Automapper. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Good to know. I still have a doubt, maybe it is even possible not to add the second `Ignore` according to the last priority point: *Inherited Ignore Property Mapping*